# Converting a docker-compose.yml file with Kompose to K8S with a build step

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kompose

I've the following `docker-compose.yml` file, I'd like to convert it to K8S configuration files.

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  api-fiber:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8666:8666
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/app/current
    networks:
      - api-network

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379



networks:
  api-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Kompose converts the resources to yaml, but skip the build section of the `api-fiber` specs. How to reference this step to make Kompose aware of it?

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't know how to build images.  You (or your CI system) will need to build the image and push it to some repository; you can add an `image:` line to give that image a known name.  The `volumes:` also just will not work in Kubernetes and Kompose is likely to generate something that renders your container inoperative; I'd also delete that block from your Compose file (and test that the plain-Docker setup works).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I naively thought Kubernetes had similar build capabilities as OpenShift. +1 for the `image:` line. I'll push my image to a registry and it should work just fine.